# Android ExpandableListview all child item in every group

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I create `ExpandableListview` in `Android`. I use custom adapter but my all child item is in every single group.

Result that I want to :

```
[ First ]       [ Second ]       [ Third ]

- AAA           - DDD           - GGG
- BBB           - EEE           - HHH
- CCC           - FFF           - III
```

('First', 'Second', and 'Third' is expandable list group name / and other is child item name)

But My list show like :

```
[ First ]       [ Second ]       [ Third ]

- AAA           - AAA           - AAA
- BBB           - BBB           - BBB
- CCC           - CCC           - CCC
- DDD           - DDD           - DDD
- EEE           - EEE           - EEE
- FFF           - FFF           - FFF
- GGG           - GGG           - GGG
- HHH           - HHH           - HHH
- III           - III           - III
```

Screenshot :
(I changed group name)

[image]

This is my code :

```
//ExpandableList
private ExpandableListView mPastMedalList;

//ListView Adapter
private ArrayList<String> mGroupList = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<Object> mChildList = null;
private ArrayList<String> mChildListContent = new ArrayList<>();

private void setList(){
    setGroupData();
    setChildGroupData();

    mPastMedalList.setAdapter(new BaseExpandableAdapter(getActivity(), mGroupList, mChildList));
    mPastMedalList.expandGroup(0); //default expand

    //click event
    mPastMedalList.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {
            setExpandableListViewHeight(parent, groupPosition);
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void setGroupData() {
    mGroupList.add("First");
    mGroupList.add("Second");
    mGroupList.add("Third");
}

private void setChildGroupData() {
    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("AAA");
    mChildListContent.add("BBB");
    mChildListContent.add("CCC");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);

    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("DDD");
    mChildListContent.add("EEE");
    mChildListContent.add("FFF");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);

    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("GGG");
    mChildListContent.add("HHH");
    mChildListContent.add("III");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);
}
```

and my adapter source:

```
public class BaseExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> groupList = null;
    private ArrayList<Object> childList = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

    public BaseExpandableAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<String> groupList, ArrayList<Object> childList){
        super();
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.groupList = groupList;
        this.childList = childList;
    }

    //return group size
    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return groupList.size();
    }

    //return child view size
    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childList.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    //return group position 
    @Override
    public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupList.get(groupPosition);
    }

    //return child view
    @Override
    public String getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>)childList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    //return group id
    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    //return child view id
    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    //each group view ROW
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rio2016_sports_olympic_header, null);
            viewHolder.header = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_header);
            viewHolder.drawer = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_drawer);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        //change icon when open or close
        if(isExpanded){ //open
            viewHolder.drawer.setImageResource(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_olympic_detail_drawer_up);
        }else{ //close
            viewHolder.drawer.setImageResource(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_olympic_detail_drawer_down);
        }

        viewHolder.header.setText(getGroup(groupPosition));

        return view;
    }

    //return child view
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null){
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rio2016_sports_olympic_item, null);
            viewHolder.medal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_medal);
            viewHolder.flag = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_flag);
            viewHolder.countries = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_countries);
            viewHolder.name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sports_olympic_list_name);
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.medal.setImageResource(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_olympic_detail_medal);
        viewHolder.flag.setImageResource(R.drawable.rio2016_sports_olympic_detail_flag);
        viewHolder.countries.setText("KOR");
        viewHolder.name.setText(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));

        return view;
    }

    //
    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        //header
        private TextView header;
        private ImageView drawer;

        //item
        private ImageView medal;
        private ImageView flag;
        private TextView countries;
        private TextView name;
    }
}
```

I wonder why don't every child item in correct each group? Please help me! Thanks, all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside Your `setChildGroupData()` function you are using same `mChildListContent` variable instead of creating new one for each of three.
You should probably do this ->

```
    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("AAA");
    mChildListContent.add("BBB");
    mChildListContent.add("CCC");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);

    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("DDD");
    mChildListContent.add("EEE");
    mChildListContent.add("FFF");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);

    mChildList = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent = new ArrayList<>();
    mChildListContent.add("GGG");
    mChildListContent.add("HHH");
    mChildListContent.add("III");
    mChildList.add(mChildListContent);
```